# Как называли «фамилию» до заимствования этого слова?

Tags: этимология

Заимствование «фамилия» вошло в русский язык только в XVIII веке. Как называлась эта часть имени раньше? Есть ли исконно русский синоним?

Answer (score 2):

Varvara Yakovleva, судя по всему - никак не называлась.

Это было что-то типа родового имени, отвечало на вопрос чей или чьих, из какого рода. Потребности в специальном термине не было.

Сами фамилии развились из отчеств, Рюковичи, Ярославичи и т.п. обозначало родовую принадлежность. И эти княжеские и боярские "фамилии" были, судя по всему, единственными фамилиями века до XV. Потом фамилии стали появляться у простого народа, зависимых слоев. По большей части были притяжательными прилагательными. Тоже нужды в специальном термине не было.

Таким образом, если я все правильно понимаю, слово фамилия (в современном значении) пришло на Русь вместе с самим понятием.

Answer (score 1):

До появления фамилий были прозвища. Говорили: такой-то ***по прозванью***...

> Само слово «фамилия» происходит от латинского familia – семья.
>   Когда-то и в русском языке «фамилия» могло означать «семья»; об этом
>   напоминают выражения «фамильное сходство», «фамильные традиции»,
>   «фамильные драгоценности». Замените здесь слово «фамильный» словом
>   «семейный», и ничего, по существу, не изменится. *Иванов, Кузнецов,
>   Верейский* ещё в прошлом веке нередко определялись как «фамильные
>   прозвания», затем стали просто говорить – фамилии. Таким образом,
>   связь между словами «семья» и «фамилия» не случайна, фамилия –
>   семейное наименование, прибавляемое к имени и отчеству человека.

[Подробно](http://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/1010455/Fedosyuk_-_Russkie_familii._Populyarnyy_etimologicheskiy_slovar.html).

См. также: [Этимология слова "семья"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8C%D1%8F);

Происхождение слов: [семья, община, ближние.](http://www.nn.ru/community/user/orthodox/?do=read&thread=2424267&topic_id=54683882&year=2012)

Comment: Не вижу ответа по существу.